# How to make a html form in a email and access the data

Tags: c#, php, email, client

I am looking for resources on how to acces a submited html-form.

The situation :

- The client sends a EMAIL message to a server. *Example : Help* [send]
- The server respons back with a htmlform-email thats need to be completed.
- The client compleets the EMAIL form and presses the submit button.

How can you acces the data from this form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you access for data from any other HTML form.

Except for those email clients where it completely breaks (which is a good reason to avoid putting forms in HTML emails and to provide a link to an HTML document served over HTTP instead), a form just submits data to the URI specified in the action attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it all depends on where the form is posting.

In the email response with the form in it, the `<form>` tag needs to have it's action tag set to a php script on your server.